# Is there a name for a sensor to linearly output values according to its supply voltage?

Tags: sensor

The MXA2500E accelerometer outputs values from 0.1 to 4.9 V @ 5 V supply; it outputs values 0.1 to 2.9 V @ 3 V supply. Is there a name for this type of scaling?

- [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/821/mcic_s_a0004994793_1-2295249.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of scaling is sometimes called **ratiometric**. The sensor's output is a ratio of the supply voltage.

Comment: It's only ratiometric if both offset *and* slope scale with the power supply. Doesn't seem to be the case for this sensor. Neither seems to scale with the supply voltage.

Comment: On the surface it looks like it's ratiometric, with a Wheatstone bridge in there.  But if you read the text you find that the sensing elements are thermopiles, not resistors.  Then if you circle back to the example schematic, you see the thermopiles aren't _quite_ drawn like resistors.  So it's an easy mistake to make if you just glance at the schematic.

Answer (score 4):

Per the *title* of your question, the answer is "ratiometric".  But that's not how that chip works -- its outputs are simply limited to the voltage input of the chip.

Ratiometric means that the device output is proportional to its input multiplied by the supply voltage.  However, especially these days, you would expect that the data sheet would say so, and that data sheet doesn't.  Moreover, the sensitivity is given as 475 to 525mV/g without mentioning the power supply level, and note 6 to the specifications table says:

> The device operates over a 3.0V to 5.25V supply range. Please note that
> sensitivity and zero g bias level will be **slightly different** at 3.0V operation.

So, this is not ratiometric.  It's just a device whose output is limited by the supply.  Since that's the norm it doesn't have a special name -- the closest I could suggest would be "not rail to rail output", or since 0.1V is pretty good in 1990's terms, perhaps "almost rail to rail output".

* There's actually infinitely many ways that this could work out -- but those are the two most likely possibilities in a chip that's useful enough to actually *sell*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that needs a special name - that's just a voltage output. The fact that it scales with the supply isn't "special"; you always need to specify the operating conditions for which a given sensor has a given input/output behaviour, and in this (very common) case, this entails the exact supply voltage.